# fixed point conversion in simulink

Tags: simulink

I have generic question. I have developed a control model in simulink and it works fine. I was trying to convert this model to fixed point , with little success. The coefficients in the float model are greater than unity. However my inputs are from 16bit ADC (Q15). Therefore, there seems to be some issues and my outputs are going haywire. Please provide me the advice. I have two coefficients in my design, a1 and a2 with values, a1= .16 and a2 =3600. I am unable to scale it to Q15 to enable proper convergence

Comment: Do you have the fixed point designer toolbox for Simulink?

Comment: my problem got solved using fixed point designer